# US census block group or county to MSAs relationships with R package

Tags: r, census, tidycensus

I am using the `tidycensus` package in R and am trying to match the US census 'block group' level data to the relevant metropolitan statistical area (MSA). I have the 'block group' to county relationship, but am trying to see if `tidycensus` or a similar R package can give me the 'block group' to MSA relationship directly, or the county to MSA relationship?

Plan B is to use the files available on the Census Bureau website, but wondering if there is a R package available to do this directly?

Comment: Here's a section from my book that explains how to do it: https://walker-data.com/census-r/spatial-analysis-with-us-census-data.html#identifying-geometries-within-a-metropolitan-area